# Top align text in flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have created a layout in which there are buttons with text.

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the flexbox to work properly on IE and figure out how to get the text to align at the top of each.

I tried `vertical-align: top;` with no luck:

**Text aligned at top**
[image]

```css
.flexbox {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.flexbox tr {
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox tr td {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
button {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<table class=flexbox>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>Hello there my name is bob and this is a test Hello there my name is bob and this is a test Hello there my name is bob and this is a test</button>
      <td style="vertical-align:top;">
        <button>B</button>
        <td>
          <button>C</button>
          <td>
            <button>D</button>
            <td>
              <button>E</button>
              <td>
                <button>GF</button>
              </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tXS6w/443/

Comment: Why are you using flexbox on a table? Without flex, vertical-align should work.

Comment: I would like all of the buttons to retain the same size no matter the text size difference.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle to work with IE now however I still cant get the text at the top

Comment: I am trying to keep the <table> as responsive as possible. Mind making a modification to my jfiddle to show me what you mean?

Comment: you have the text aligning properly on every browser!!! However on chrome. it comes outside of the button

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tXS6w/446/   - check out the updates I made. You are so close... it works in all browsers but on re-size it fails.

Comment: Do you necessarily have to use the `<button>` element? Can you use `<a>` or `<input>` instead? The `<button>` element isn't playing nice with flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox doesn't play nice with the `button` element. In fact, [`button` doesn't even recognize flex properties in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276).

Here's an alternative that may work for you. It's pure CSS, responsive and works across browsers (tested on Chrome, FF and IE11). Also, no `height`s needed.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox > section {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fafafa 0%, #ddd 100%);
}
.flexbox > section > a {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.flexbox > section:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f1f1f1 0%, #d1d1d1 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <section>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      Hello there my name is bob and this is a test Hello there my name
      is bob and this is a test Hello there my name is bob and this is a
      test
    </a>
  </section>
  <section>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">B</a>
  </section>
  <section>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">C</a>
  </section>
  <section>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">D</a>
  </section>
  <section>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">E</a>
  </section>
  <section>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">GF</a>
  </section>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXS6w/457/)

Comment: I will have to say I am a little confused by your example, and I keep getting {"error": "Please use POST request"}....and when I click on one button the page tries to refresh or something.

Comment: This answer was intended to solve the layout problem. The 'button' functionality was not considered during this step. That's another issue. What's supposed to happen when the user clicks the button?

Comment: there is an angularjs ng-show and ng-repeat in the button that takes thes user to the next page.

Comment: I updated demo to prevent click error and keep focus on layout design. You may need to use JS to make the `<a>` element function as you wish. Otherwise, you can use `<button>` (which presumably would use JS, as well), but you will lose the layout.

Comment: I ended up using your section idea, and setting it as a button with bootstrap... it works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change all your `button`s, except the ones from the first column, for example:

```
<button>B</button>
```

To have a `span` wrapping its content text:

```
<button><span>B</span></button>
```

Now you can set the `span` to fill the `button`'s space as you need:

```
button > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 3px;
}
```

Don't forget to `position` `button` as `relative`:

```
button {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

Also, as a side note, it is a good practice to always indent your html and close the tags properly (in this case, the `td`s' closing tags were missing).

[See also a working responsive Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tXS6w/450/)

Comment: Tried this already. Doesn't work. Add the `<span>` tags to the first column `<button>` text. You'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Michael_B What if the `span` tag is not required for the first column?

Comment: Well then the problem would be easily solved with positioning properties, and your answer should be accepted.

Comment: I agree with michael_b

Comment: And, it is responsive, as required. =]

Comment: Everything is working but the main problem is as soon as CSS sees flex it stretches the button I just want to move the text to the top so its all aligned without spans with flex.