# Flex / Grid layouts not working on button or fieldset elements

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to center inner elements of a `<button>`-tag with flexbox's `justify-content: center`. But Safari does not center them. I can apply the same style to any other tags and it works as intended (see the `<p>`-tag). Only the button is left-aligned.

Try Firefox or Chrome and you can see the difference.

Is there any user agent style I have to overwrite? Or any other solution to this problem?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
button, p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>
    <span>Test</span>
    <span>Test</span>
  </button>
  <p>
    <span>Test</span>
    <span>Test</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

And a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/z3sfwtn2/2/

Comment: Similar issue: [Why can't <fieldset> be flex containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28078681/1529630)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

### The Problem

In some browsers the `<button>` element doesn't accept changes to its `display` value, beyond switching between `block` and `inline-block`. This means that a `<button>` element cannot be a flex or grid container, or a `<table>`, either.

In addition to `<button>` elements, you may find this constraint applying to `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` elements, as well.

See the bug reports below for more details.

*Note: Although they cannot be flex containers, `<button>` elements can be flex items.*

---

### The Solution

There is a simple and easy cross-browser workaround to this problem:

**Wrap the content of the `button` in a `span`, and make the `span` the flex container.**

Adjusted HTML (wrapped `button` content in a `span`)

```
<div>
    <button>
        <span><!-- using a div also works but is not valid HTML -->
            <span>Test</span>
            <span>Test</span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <p>
        <span>Test</span>
        <span>Test</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Adjusted CSS (targeted `span`)

```
button > span, p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[**Revised Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3sfwtn2/7/)

---

### References / Bug Reports

[Flexbox on a `<button>` blockifies the contents but doesn't establish a flex formatting context](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1176786)

> User (Oriol Brufau): *The children of the `<button>` are blockified, as dictates the flexbox spec. However, the `<button>` seems to establish a block formatting context instead of a flex one.*
>
> User (Daniel Holbert): *That is effectively what the HTML spec requires. Several HTML container-elements are "special" and effectively ignore their CSS `display` value in Gecko [aside from whether it's inline-level vs. block-level]. `<button>` is one of these. `<fieldset>` & `<legend>` are as well.*

[Add support for display:flex/grid and columnset layout inside `<button>` elements](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869)

> User (Daniel Holbert):
>
> *`<button>` is not implementable (by browsers) in pure CSS, so they are a bit of a black box, from the perspective of CSS. This means that
>   they don't necessarily react in the same way that e.g. a `<div>`
>   would.*
>
> *This isn't specific to flexbox -- e.g. we don't render scrollbars if you put `overflow:scroll` on a button, and we don't render it as a
>   table if you put `display:table` on it.*
>
> *Stepping back even further, this isn't specific to `<button>`. Consider `<fieldset>` and `<table>` which also have special rendering
>   behavior.*
>
> *And old-timey HTML elements like `<button>` and `<table>` and `<fieldset>` simply do not support custom `display` values, other than
>   for the purposes of answering the very high-level question of "is this
>   element block-level or inline-level", for flowing other content around
>   the element.*

Also see:

- [Flexbug #9: Some HTML elements can't be flex containers](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-9)
- [10. Some HTML elements can't be grid containers](https://github.com/rachelandrew/gridbugs#10-some-html-elements-cant-be-grid-containers)

Comment: I get why it might not work for `<button>`s, but why on earth is it not working for `<fieldset>` either? Shouldn't that element be considered a regular block level element that is valid for a flex container?

Comment: @fritzmg. Agreed. The rule probably pre-exists CSS3 technologies, such as Flex and Grid, and should be re-evaluated.

Comment: So we would like to prevent a button from being misused... but could still misuse something else and place it inside of the button. Sounds about as logic as the rest of the web...

Comment: Finding this thread in 2019 and noting that `<button>` works well as a `flex-container` in Chrome 76 and Safari 12.1. But both are buggy when the button is a child of `display:grid`. See https://codepen.io/urlyman/pen/rXqmqY. Firefox 68 holds up.

Comment: Do you have a citation for `<button>` not being designed to be a flex (or grid) container? It looks like the browsers regard the inability to set display on these elements as a bug and are actively fixing them.

Comment: @Michael_B Consider adding a reference to the actual text where you make the assertion. No need to reply to my comment - if you add it to the text where you make the assertion I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: Also why isn't a `div` inside a button valid HTML?

Comment: A `div` can't be a child of a `button` because, if you think of it in old-school HTML, a block-level element can't be a child of an inline-level element. But today, with HTML5, the technically correct answer is that [a `button` element can only accept *Phrasing Content*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). A `span` represents *Phrasing Content*, but a `div` does not. A `div` represents *Flow Content*. [More details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories)

Comment: Unbelievable! :)

Answer (score 12):

Here is my simplest hack.

```
button::before,
button::after {
    content: '';
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. How would you fix this: https://codepen.io/nuthinking/pen/d64da8788475c1c9c09a869f7403156d?editors=1100

Answer (score 3):

Starting Chrome 83, [the `button` now works as `inline-grid/grid/inline-flex/flex`](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5213452823953408).

Here is a snippet (for those using Chrome 83 and up):

```css
button {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 2rem;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 4rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!-- 

The align-items keyword should fail in Chrome 81 or earlier, but work in Chrome 83 or later. To see the error, the button needs styles that make it more of an extrinsic container. In other words, it needs a height or width set. 
 
-->
<button>Hi</button>
<input type="button" value="Hi">
```