# How to use flex to align button with centered text but icon to one side?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm looking for suggestions on how to create this button using flex with as little html as possible. It has centered text but the icon is aligned to one side. Most important, the two are vertical-aligned in the middle.

[image: Button with centered text and icon aligned to the side]

The problem I have: once I setup the flex to `align-items` along the horizontal, I can no longer control the vertical centering without adding additional HTML containers around each item.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/mwwy6bg7/3/

Let's assume that the `height` and `padding` on the `button` are not consistent, because there are other use-cases where I've had this same scenario, and the centered-string might be two or three lines long [while the icon is only one line]. So I cannot use `padding` or `absolute` positioning.

Up to this point, I've stuck to using non-flex because it uses less HTML. But I've found myself using `absolute` positions in cases as a result.

**Solved:** requires combining flexbox and position-absolute. Just need to apply flexbox twice. See: https://jsfiddle.net/mwwy6bg7/8/

```
<a href="/" class="button">
  Button with a long multiline label
  <span class="icon">&gt;</span>
</a>

.button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #f7f7f7;

  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font: 16px arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #595959;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
a .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D, because this question appears to be about flex alignment in a `button` element, this may be a more relevant dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276

Comment: Well, it's called a "button" but whether an actual `<button>` is being used isn't clear but it's relevant. Flexbox can't do this anyway without some 'hacks' as we know.

Comment: Frankly, I'd be using a background image for the icon and then the flexbox issue doesn't arise.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's an ng-material "button", so it could be either hyperlink or button. I notice the browser-standard `<button>` tends to vertical-align middle by default.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm using svg-sprite for the icons (to prevent blurry images on high-resolution devices). That caused certain limitations, one being there's no proper way to use it in a background image.