# How can I center text in a container that's too small?

Tags: css

I want to use CSS to create a "+" button. The following [nearly works](https://jsfiddle.net/jv03cdof/):

```
<p><span class="a">+</span>Foo</p>
<p><span class="b">+</span>Foo</p>
```

with

```
.a
{
  width:3ex;
  height:3ex;
  line-height: 3ex;
}

.b
{
  width: 1ex;
  height: 1ex;
  line-height: 1ex;
}

.a, .b
{
  display:inline-block;
  /*display:table-cell;*/
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin: 0 1ex;
}
```

This renders in Firefox as:

[image]

Nearly there. I'd just like it to still center the plus sign in the case that the containing span is too narrow, so that it spills over both sides symmetrically.

Is that possible?

Comment: I'm sorry but don't try to reinvent the wheel, use fontawesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox actually works perfectly here.

```css
span {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  font-size: 96px;
  border: 1px solid grey; /* demo only */
  display: inline-block;
  margin:32px; /* demo only */
}
span.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="flex">+</span>
```

Comment: Note, this may not work when applied directly to `<button>` elements [in certain browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35466231/1054633).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution you are looking for is:

```
<div style=“position: relative;”>
  <span style=“position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,0)”>
     blah
   </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: In my own use-case, this was the most appropriate solution, thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is what you are refering to but you can wrap your `+` inside another `span` and then use `margin: -50%`.

```css
.a
{
  width:3ex;
  height:3ex;
  line-height: 3ex;
}

.b
{
  width: 1ex;
  height: 1ex;
  line-height: 1ex;
}

.a, .b
{
  display:inline-block;
  /*display:table-cell;*/
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin: 0 1ex;
}

.text{
  margin: -50%;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="a">+</span>Foo</p>
<p><span class="b"><span class="text">+</span></span>Foo</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not sure how you're planning to change icon sizes for each Plus button. But here is a try.

Using the Same Fiddle

Try it.

```
.a
{
  width:3ex;
  height:3ex;
  line-height: 3ex;
}

.b
{
  width: 1ex;
  height: 1ex;
  line-height: 1ex;

}
.a:after, .b:after {
    content: '+';
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.a, .b
{
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin: 0 1ex;
}
```

The HTML

```
<p><span class="a"></span>Foo</p>
<p><span class="b"></span>Foo</p>
```

With this. At-least your .b icon with small font-size will be centered.