# Unable to hide flex items by changing width or flex-basis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I want to achieve this effect:

In the default state, there are four buttons. One of them is a 'Move' button.

[image: Beginning]

When a user clicks on it, I want to expand the button and show additional text and input.

[image: End, expanded state]

However I am unable to achieve the 'default state'. The 'To ' always appears. I have tried `flex-basis` and `width: 0px` but there is no effect, like so

[image: not working]

How can I hide a flex box element without using `display:none`. The main reason for not using `display` is because I want to expand the widget with some css animation on width.

Here is the HTML code:

```
  <div class="multiselect-controls">
    <span class="multiselect-controls-container medium-theme">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-multi-select multi-edit">
        <span class="multiselect-text">Edit</span>
      </button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-multi-select multi-copy">
        <span class="multiselect-text">Copy</span>
      </button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-multi-select multi-move" onclick="expandMe();">
        <span class="multiselect-text">Move</span>
        <span class="multi-move-input">
          to <input class="multi-move-to-target" type='text'></input>
        </span>
      </button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-multi-select multi-delete">Delete</button>
      <span class='icon icon-cross close-multiselect-controls'></span>
    </span>
  </div>
```

and `css(less)` code:

```
btn-multi-select {
  display:flex;
  width: 100px;
}

.multi-move-input {
  flex-basis: 0px;
  // overflow: hidden;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.expanded {
  &.multi-move {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .multi-move-input {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
}

.multi-move-to-target {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  color: black;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function expandMe(event) {
  $('.multi-move').toggleClass('expanded');
}
```

The code is also available here: http://codepen.io/kongakong/pen/amdrJZ

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXLPQm

Comment: @Michael_B thanks for the great answer! If you can expand your comment into an answer I will upvote and accept.

Comment: @Michael_B - `.addClass('expanded')` instead of the toggle would work better for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I hide a flex box element without using `display:none`? The main reason for not using `display` is because I want to expand the widget with some css animation on width.

You can use `max-width`, which is an [animatable property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties-).

Start it at `0`, then have it expand to some extra large number. The element will only expand enough to fit content.

```
.multi-move-input {
  display: inline-flex;
  max-width: 0;
  transition: .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.expanded {
  &.multi-move { }
  .multi-move-input {
    max-width: 200px;
    transition: 1s;
  }
}
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXLPQm)

Two things to consider:

1. I've only focused on the hide/show transition, which is your question. But note that the input is inside the button's clickable area. This means when you try to input data it will fire the transition and close the button. This can be fixed with a bit of re-structuring (HTML) and/or re-targeting (CSS).
2. Button elements as flex containers may cause unexpected behavior in some browsers. See this post: *[Flexbox not working on <button> element in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276)*