# Make Hide/Flex Items in QML

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside

Is there anyway to replicate this type of hide/flex effect that you can see in this person's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481314/unable-to-hide-flex-items-by-changing-width-or-flex-basis) using QML? I am also using QT Creator to aid with the UI building so in the case of my baseline example that I am working with below, I have a button that when pressed, will reveal a white rectangle that will contain more content inside it in the future. And when this white rectangle appears, the grey rectangle that the white one is inside also lengthens accordingly, basically wrapping it. In the process, the Some text is also pushed down like in the after.png When the button is pressed again, the white rectangle should disappear and the Some text should move back up.

Other than using hide to program part of the functionality, I don't know how to make the objects move around like that. Here's the code that corresponds to the after.png

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Item {
    id: item1
    width: 800
    height: 600

    Page {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            id: bound
            color: "#cad2d7"
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0

            Button {
                id: button
                x: 8
                y: 8
                text: qsTr("Button")
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: rectangle
                x: 0
                y: 74
                width: 800
                height: 200
                color: "#ffffff"
            }

            Text {
                id: text1
                x: 14
                y: 293
                text: qsTr("Some text")
                font.pixelSize: 60
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am also using Python (PySide6) but am not sure if some sort of controller would have to be scripted to control the elements.
[after.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn2qU.png)
[before.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jqIZ.png) (Note the white that you see in the before.png is just the white background)

Comment: please provide your attempt to do that. or some code that you want to apply this effect to.

Comment: @folibis I just added some simplified code from my project and edited my question some more so that it is hopefully more clear on my intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for something like an [accordion design pattern](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/AccordionMenu) where you can expand to show normally-invisible content. In the scenario you described, a simple approach would be a `ColumnLayout` inside of a grey base `Rectangle`, where the visibility of your middle content is toggled. Here is a full stand-alone example:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        color: "lightgrey"
        width: parent.width
        height: column.implicitHeight // note this rectangle derives its height from column, and column derives its height from its children's implicitHeight or Layout.prefererredHeight

        ColumnLayout {
            id: column
            width: parent.width
            spacing: 0

            Button {
                text: qsTr("Button")
                onClicked: {
                    middleRectangle.visible = !middleRectangle.visible // toggle middleRectangle visibility
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: middleRectangle
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 100
                visible: false  // note default is NOT visible

                Text {
                    text: qsTr("New text")
                    font.pixelSize: 60
                }
            }

            Text {
                text: qsTr("Some text")
                font.pixelSize: 60
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Things to note are:

- Items that are `visible: false` do not take up space in `ColumnLayout`/`RowLayout`, however, this is not the case with the different positioners `Column` and `Row`
- The base `Rectangle` that encompasses everything derives its height from the `ColumnLayout`, which in turn derives its height from its children
- The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481314/unable-to-hide-flex-items-by-changing-width-or-flex-basis) you mentioned does not seem to follow your description's design, so this approach is not necessarily applicable in that scenario, but some parts of it would work, e.g. toggling visibility.

Comment: I see, I think the general principle is still the same, but I'm not looking to create a flexible tab bar. I think you hit the nail on the head with the accordion design pattern because that's exactly what I'm looking for. This really helps; thank you for explaining the working example and the extra clarification on `Column`/`Row` vs `ColumnLayout`/`RowLayout` because I wasn't sure about those.
{hopefully I can upvote your answer once I get to 15 rep)

Comment: I upvoted your question so now you should have enough rep :)