# Flexbox inline-flex bug in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I'm looking to use Flexbox to align an svg and the text within a button and all is working well in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox there seems to be a problem.

This codepen should demonstrate the problem live.
Please note that I am pulling in https://github.com/mastastealth/sass-flex-mixin/blob/master/_flex.scss as an external CSS sheet in the codepen.

http://codepen.io/dominicchapman/pen/EgNgoq

SCSS as follows:

```
.Button {
  border: 0 none;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;

  .Icon {
        fill: white; 
    }

    &:hover, &:active {
        background: red;
    }
}

.Button__icon {
  @include inline-flex;
  @include align-items(center);
  .Icon {
    margin-right: 11px;
    height:16px;
    width:6px
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems [this was already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/1529630). I won't close right now in case I misunderstood the problem, I don't have other browsers at hand to compare the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Firefox does not fully support flexbox in `<button>` elements.

It's strange because the child boxes are blockified, and that's why you see the contents in different lines. However, the button does not seem to establish a flex formatting context. All flex properties are ignored.

I would understand not supporting flexbox on buttons, but IMO this strange mix is nonsense. However, mozilla people didn't see any problem.

Luckily they reconsidered and [bug 984869](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869) was reopened. But no work is actively been done on it.

Comment: "However, mozilla people didn't see any problem." Yep, Mozilla is known to deviate from the standard simply because they can. (I mean, *everyone* does that, but Moz's reason isn't "screw the spec" as is the case with the others, but rather "the spec lets me do whatever I want". And boy do they *milk* that freedom.)

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, they say "That's a bit hand-wavy", "The spec on all this stuff is basically nonexistent", ...