# Flexbox on button parents do not work on on children psuedo selector content in mobile chrome/safari

Tags: css, flexbox

This is a pretty specific problem... but flexbox rules don't seem to work on psuedo selector elements when the parent is a button in mobile safari and chrome.

Here is a codepen to clearly demonstrate this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKaRXY

In desktop browsers, both blocks should have a "t" in the middle. In mobile browsers, only one has this "t" in the middle.

I have literally copy and pasted the full computed styles from the "div" to the "button" and it still fails for some reason.

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </button>

  <div class="button">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>



.container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
  background: #dbe8ff;
  width: 500px;
}


.child:before {
  content: "t";
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background: #fff09b;
}
```

Comment: possible guidance: [**Flexbox not working on `<button>` element in some browsers**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just on mobile... Your current layout is never applying flex style to the pseudo elements.

The pseudo elements are children of the elemnt on wich they are declare. In this case, they are children of .child. So, they are grand-children of button, and your styles don't work.

If you want to style the pseudos this way, you have to set display: flex on **child** instead.

The reason that you see the *t* centered is because the dimension of child are adjusted to the dimension of the pseudo, and so this one can only be placed centered.

Comment: this is brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, on your second time you have copied as`<div class="button"> instead of <button class="button">`

Comment: I think you've mis understood the question. The exact point was that the flex renders differently for <div> elements vs <button> elements on mobile.