# How to solve this two issues on this Codepen?

Tags: css, animation, flexbox, css-transitions, css-animations

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/leocavalcante/pen/gLybee)

1. <s>Why setting `width: 100%` on `span` doesn't work?</s>
2. There is someway to archive the same result without `@keyframes dummy` and `setTimeout`?

EDIT

1. Enlightened thanks to @Michael_B, seams to be a bug with `button` tag and `flex`, switching to `div` or `a` works. If you have more info about it, please share!

Comment: 1. Narrow the question at one issue .. 2. Include the code on the question

Comment: The `width: 100%` doesn't work on the `span` because the parent container (the `button`) has `flex-direction: column`. Why I don't know yet. It seems to work fine with `flex-direction: row`. It may be a bug. Be aware that `button` elements are generally not reliable as flex containers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276

Comment: Thank you @Michael_B. Switching to `div` or `a` makes `span` `width:100%` work. Just wondering why too, always thought that tags are just semantically distinct (despite styling), but it seams that they have behavioral differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this article on restarting CSS animations:
https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

This clarifies the dirt of setting a dummy animation before the true animation.