# Align right side of a group of labels

Tags: html

I'm making an HTML page with a list of fields for filling out billing info.
Since the labels are in-line, their width is determined by the text contained in them, thus making them different widths which makes the input boxes unaligned. This makes a very ugly, unorganized look.

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Billing Information</legend><br>
    Card Number: <input type="text"><br><br>
    Expiration Month: <input type="number"><br><br>
    Expiration Year: <input type="number"><br><br>
    Name on Card: <input type="text"><br><br>
    Address: <input type="text"><br><br>
    City: <input type="text"><br><br>
    State: <input type="text"><br><br>
    Country: <input type="text"><br><br>
    ZIP Code: <input type="number"><br><br>
</fieldset><br>
```

What do I need to do to my HTML code to **align the right side of the labels** and the left side of the input boxes?

Comment: do you need to align input on left side or right side

Comment: Why don't you use `<label>`'s for the labels then style them, it's more semantically correct and accessible. You could also group each set of `<label>` and `<input>` in a list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use table structure for your lists of fields for proper alignment.

```html
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Billing Information</legend>
        <table>
          <tr><td>Card Number:</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Expiration Month:</td><td> <input type="number"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Expiration Year:</td><td> <input type="number"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Name on Card:</td><td> <input type="text"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address:</td><td> <input type="text"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>City:</td><td> <input type="text"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>State:</td><td> <input type="text"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Country:</td><td> <input type="text"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>ZIP Code:</td><td> <input type="number"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the simple answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use tables or use `display: table-row` & `display: table-cell` css to simulate table cell layouts as following:

```css
fieldset {display: inline-block; padding: 10px 20px;} /* 'display: inline-block' is not necessary, just for appearance */

.row {display: table-row; }
.lbl {display: table-cell; text-align:right; padding: 8px 5px;}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Billing Information</legend>
    
    <div class="row"><span class="lbl">Card Number: </span><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="row"><span class="lbl">Expiration Month: </span><input type="number"></div>
    <div class="row"><span class="lbl">Expiration Year: </span><input type="number"></div>
    <!-- ... /-->
</fieldset><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find it much easier if you put your elements into suitable containers and use CSS to do the hard work.

```
<style type="text/css">
    label {
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 10em;
    }
</style>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Billing Information</legend><br>
        <p><label for="card-number">Card Number:</label><input type="text" name="card-number" id="card-number"></p>
        <p><label for="expiration-month">Expiration Month:</label><input type="text" name="expiration-month" id="expiration-month"></p>
        <!-- etc -->
</fieldset>
```

Here the `label` does 3 jobs:

- It creates a clickable text to activate your input box.
- It makes the purpose of the text clear for screen readers and other software.
- You can easily apply CSS to the element.

The `label` element can either be wrapped around the input element:

```
<label>Expiration Month: <input …></label>
```

or attached with the `for` attribute. The `for` attribute references an **id**, which is *independent* of the `name` attribute. As you see in the example, they are often set to the same value.

In the CSS, we set the width to something reasonable. However, the `label` needs to be displayed as an `inline-block` for the width to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flexbox` to fix your problem.
Wrap the container `fieldset` using `display: flex`, Set the `flex-direction` as `column`. Wrap the children inside a `div` and set the `flex-grow` property for the `span` element as `1`.

> Using flexbox will take care of responsiveness.

Refer [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

```css
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}

span {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Billing Information</legend>
  <div><span>Card Number: </span><input type="text"> </div>
  <div><span>Expiration Month:</span> <input type="number"></div>
  <div><span> Expiration Year:</span> <input type="number"></div>
  <div><span>Name on Card:</span> <input type="text"> </div>
  <div><span>Address:</span> <input type="text"> </div>
  <div><span>City:</span> <input type="text"></div>
  <div><span>State: </span><input type="text"></div>
  <div><span>Country:</span> <input type="text"></div>
  <div><span>ZIP Code:</span> <input type="number"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: [Flexbox not working on `button` or `fieldset` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276)