# inline-flex input element breaks to new line in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have a few html elements next to each other in a container positioned with `display:inline-flex`.

This works well for button elements, but as soon as I try to add an `input type="text"` element, the textbox is placed below the buttons (only in Internet Explorer 11; not sure about IE10 or below).

It works as expected (textbox in same line as buttons) in Firefox, Chrome and even Edge.

How can I get IE to display this correctly?

See jsFiddle for full html and css code to illustrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/vm2kcwd9/1/

```css
.container {
  height: 2em;
}

.container>* {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <button>test</button>
  <button>test 2</button>
  <button>test 3</button>
  <input type="text" value="hello" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE11 is known for having many [**flex-related bugs**](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs).

A simple and easy solution in this case would be to make the parent a flex container:

```css
.container {
  display: flex; /* new; forces all children into a single row */
  height: 2em;
}

.container>* {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  /* vertical-align: top; <--- not necessary anymore */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;  /* for demo only */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test 2</button>
  <button>test 3</button>
  <input type="text" value="hello" />
</div>
```

Also, since you're making `button` elements into flex containers, consider this:

- [Flexbox not working on <button> element in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276)

Comment: Well, that was easy, thank you. Although, that slighty changes the behavior of the elements inside the container as well. For example: I had to add flex-shrink: 0; to the children to prevent them from getting shrunk (which does not occur when the container has no display: flex).

Comment: Yes, flex-shrink is enabled by default. Still, the benefits far outweigh any transitional adjustments. Now you don't need vertical-align. Now you can use flex properties.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution just add `display:flex` to parent instead

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align-items: center; you might not need this */
  height: 2em;
}

.container>* {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test 2</button>
  <button>test 3</button>
  <input type="text" value="hello" />
</div>
```