# Bootstrap 4 .form-inline not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

I have a form in an application using Bootstrap 4. It renders as I want it to in all browsers, except Internet Explorer 11.

I have used Bootstrap's `.form-inline` class because according to the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms)

> Use the `.form-inline` class to display a series of labels, form controls, and buttons on a single horizontal row.

**The correct rendering of the form looks like this**. The screenshot below was taken from Chrome v80:

[image]

In Internet Explorer 11 it renders as follows.

[image]

The markup is as follows.

```
<div class="row">
    <form method="get" class="form-inline" action="#"> 

        <div class="col">   
            <label for="date_start" class="mr-2 float-left">From</label>
            <div class="input-group date mr-5" id="dateStart" data-target-input="nearest">
                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#dateStart" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="dateStart" value="2020-03-17" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#dateStart" autocomplete="off">  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <label for="date_end" class="mr-2 float-left">To</label>
            <div class="input-group date mr-5" id="dateEnd" data-target-input="nearest">
                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#dateEnd" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="dateEnd" value="2020-03-24" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#dateEnd" autocomplete="off">  
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md-top-pad">View Notifications <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

    </form>
</div>
```

If I remove the `.form-inline` in Internet Explorer 11 using Developer Tools the layout is more usable but still broken.

[image]

I read [inline-flex input element breaks to new line in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429965/inline-flex-input-element-breaks-to-new-line-in-ie11) and tried swapping my `.row` with a `.container`. This seems to help but it centres the form and therefore doesn't look as I want in other (non IE 11) browsers. It also makes the `input` fields look much longer than desired.

[image]

Surely it is possible to left align the form and have it all on one line?

What is the problem with this and how can I fix it for IE 11 in a way that won't break it for other browsers? I want to render it as per the first screenshot, consistently in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I compared with the [official demo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms) which can work well in IE 11, it seems that the issue is with `<div class="col">`. The elements in the form are not wrapped by `div .col` in the official demo. I removed them and it can work well in IE 11 and other browsers.

[Online demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/c01mt3e6/)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form method="get" class="form-inline" action="#">

  <label for="date_start" class="mr-2 float-left">From</label>
  <div class="input-group date mr-5" id="dateStart" data-target-input="nearest">
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#dateStart" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="dateStart" value="2020-03-17" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#dateStart" autocomplete="off">
  </div>

  <label for="date_end" class="mr-2 float-left">To</label>
  <div class="input-group date mr-5" id="dateEnd" data-target-input="nearest">
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#dateEnd" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="dateEnd" value="2020-03-24" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#dateEnd" autocomplete="off">
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md-top-pad">View Notifications <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

</form>
```