# Button with display: flex does not work in Safari. Causing size and alignment issues

Tags: ios, css, safari, flexbox

I'm having some problem with display: flex in both Safari and iOS Safari.
Safari has alignment issues and iOS Safari has both alignment and size issues. Is this expected or a valid bug in Safari?

Edit: Also, height in percentage on the child SVG inside the Button does not work either. This works in all other browsers.
I mane another more advanced example with SVG elements, and I added an anchor to compare to the button. [More advanced example here](https://codepen.io/JonWallsten/pen/YQKzXL)

[My simple example](https://codepen.io/JonWallsten/pen/VboJEg)

```
HTML:
<div class="flex">
  <div class="col col-1">
    <button class="sub-col">
      <span class="span"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="sub-col">2</div>
    <div class="sub-col">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2"></div>
  <div class="col col-3"></div>
</div>


CSS:
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 80vh;
  background: #666666;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  display: inherit;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #ccffcc;
}
.col-1 {
  flex: 0 0 10vh;
  background: #ffcccc;
}
.col-3 {
  flex: 0 0 10vh;
  background: #ccccff;
}

.sub-col {
  display: inherit;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ffaaaa;
}
```

**Screenshots:**

This is what it should look like, and does in Chrome, FF and Edge (Haven't tested IE)

[image: Chome, FF and Edge]

This is what it looks like in Safari

[image: Safari Desktop]

And this is iOS Safari

[image: iOS Safari]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox not working on <button> element in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flexbox-not-working-on-button-element-in-some-browsers)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't set display flex to button and fieldset elements. chk below link. Wrap your element with div or span tags

https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#9-some-html-elements-cant-be-flex-containers

Comment: I see, must have missed that when I skimmed through that page. 
I've already switched to a-tags instead. Unfortunately there are more issues though. Maybe using Flexbox is not the best idea.

Comment: Can you describe the issues? Perhaps I could be of some help.

Answer (score 7):

The button element, and a couple other elements for that matter, cannot be flex containers in some browsers. Safari is one of them.

You can try a simple solution though, if you like. The idea is, you wrap your .span inside .span-wrapper. Then you let .span-wrapper be your flex container.

Like that:

HTML:

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="col col-1">
    <button class="sub-col">
      <span class="span-wrapper">
        <span class="span"></span>
      </span>
    </button>
    <div class="sub-col">2</div>
    <div class="sub-col">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2"></div>
  <div class="col col-3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 80vh;
  background: #666666;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  display: inherit;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #ccffcc;
}
.col-1 {
  flex: 0 0 10vh;
  background: #ffcccc;
}
.col-3 {
  flex: 0 0 10vh;
  background: #ccccff;
}

.sub-col {
  display: inherit;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ffaaaa;
}

.span-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: I ended up switching to hyperlinks instead. So now I'm trying to figure out why height/max-height in percentage for the child SVG element is not working in Safari. 2 steps forwards, 1 step back...