# Style a HTML form with fieldsets and labels to have a 3 colum layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid, fieldset

## The problem

### The question

How should I style a form, so that I get my desired 3 column layout under the following constraints:

- The layout works, even if the the html files are not static (dynamic number of checkboxes, ...)

  Decent browser support (bonus points if edgeHTML 15 supports the solution)

  The fieldsets stay in the DOM, because removing them would have side effects (radio buttons would not be grouped, checkboxes and radios would not be disabled anymore, ...)

  Prefered: No changes in html files needed

  Prefered: HTML and CSS only

If this is not possible with a 3 column design, a 2 column design would be a possible alternative.

### The basics

So basically I have a form like this:

```html
<form>
  <h2>A title</h2>
  <label>
    Some text input
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    Some more text
    <textarea></textarea>
  </label>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Some options</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      2
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      3
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

and would like to get a layout like this:

```
    +-----------------+------------------+------------------+
    | A title                                               |
    +-----------------+------------------+------------------+
    | Some text input | (                                 ) |
    +-----------------+------------------+------------------+
    | Some more text  | [                                 ] |
    +-----------------+------------------+------------------+
    | Some options    | [] 1             | [] 3             |
    +                 +------------------+------------------+
    |                 | [] 2             |                  |
    +-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

## The approaches

So I came up with two main approaches because I don't want to change my HTML files just for styling purposes:

### Apply the grid on the form

If I style my form with `display: grid;` and my labels and fieldsets with `display: contents;`, I would have one grid for all elements in the grid and can be sure, that no individual grid styles different, but I will encounter a [bug](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) in most browsers, which renders the content inaccessible.

#### +

- Only 1 grid for all elements

#### −

- Bug which renders the content inaccessible
- Styling as margins of fieldsets and labels are lost
- Need to take care of custom elements, because in this project, we have a lot of custom components, that could destroy the layout

So I would have something like

```css
fieldset, 
fieldset legend,
fieldset label,
fieldset input{
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

form > h2 {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

form > label,
form > fieldset {
  display: contents;
}

form > label > input[type="text"],
form > label > textarea {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

form > fieldset label:nth-of-type(odd) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

form > fieldset label:nth-of-type(even) {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h2>A title</h2>
  <label>
    Some text input
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    Some more text
    <textarea></textarea>
  </label>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Some options</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      2
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      3
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

### Apply the grid on the labels and fieldsets

On the other side, I tried to apply the grid on the labels and fieldsets directly, so that I don't have to care about elements, that span an entire column, but I encounter a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076747/grid-layout-on-fieldset-bug-on-chrome) in chrome and new edge browsers, that `display: grid;` doesn't work on fieldsets. As you can see, in the codepen above, I could get my desired layout working, with the mentioned workaround, but I had to change my HTML files.

#### +

- no need to care about nested elements
- Decent support

#### −

- Individual grids, which could potentially behave differently
- Need to make changes in HTML files, just for styling reasons

So I have something like

```css
fieldset, 
fieldset legend,
fieldset label,
fieldset input{
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form > fieldset,
form > label {
  margin-top: 2 * $defaultSpacing;
}

form > fieldset,
form > label {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

form > fieldset legend {
  grid-column: 1;
}

form > fieldset label:nth-of-type(odd) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

form > fieldset label:nth-of-type(even) {
  grid-column: 3;
}

form > label input[type="text"],
form > label textarea,
form > label * {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h2>A title</h2>
  <label>
    Some text input
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    Some more text
    <textarea></textarea>
  </label>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Some options</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      2
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      3
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Or the workaround:

```css
fieldset, 
fieldset legend,
fieldset label,
fieldset input{
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form > fieldset .fieldset,
form > label {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

form > fieldset legend {
  grid-column: 1;
}

form > fieldset label:nth-of-type(odd) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

form > fieldset label:nth-of-type(even) {
  grid-column: 3;
}

form > label input[type="text"],
form > label textarea,
form > label * {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h2>A title</h2>
  <label>
    Some text input
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    Some more text
    <textarea></textarea>
  </label>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <legend>Some options</legend>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        1
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        2
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        3
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't normally say to have LESS information, but in this case, if there's any way to boil it down to a single issue, I think you might have more success getting an answer. Leave it like this for awhile, but if you don't get any bites, try focusing on a specific aspect.

Comment: Applying the grid on the form is the way to go, at least in 2023. Issues with `display: contents` rendering contents inaccessible have been resolved.