# Can html list items (li) be set to display: grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

For example I am trying to create a footer with 4 links spaced evenly with the following code

```css
footer{
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 2px;

}
#footer_list{
    display:inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;

    list-style-type: none;
}
.footer_list_item{
    color: #001f3f !important;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <ul id="footer_list">
        <li class="footer_list_item">A Blah Blah Production</li>
        <li class="footer_list_item">Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx</li>
        <li class="footer_list_item">Email: support@company.com</li>
        <li class="footer_list_item" href="#">Career Info</li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vq9b7c0e/3/

Is setting a `list` to `display:grid` invalid? As all of the items seem to be randomly spaced

Answer (score 0):

Dont use "href" in `<li>`

I do not know exactly what is going on, but it may help you -

```css
footer{
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 2px;

}
#footer_list{
    display:inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.footer_list_item{
    color: #001f3f !important;
}
.footer_list_item a {
     word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <ul id="footer_list">
        <li class="footer_list_item">A Blah Blah Production</li>
        <li class="footer_list_item">Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx</li>
        <li class="footer_list_item">Email: <a href="#">support@company.com</a></li>
        <li class="footer_list_item"><a href="#">Career Info</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qhv40j1d/

Answer (score 0):

Setting an HTML element to `display: grid` (or `inline-grid`) is perfectly valid.

According to the W3C definition, [the `display` property applies to **all elements**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#the-display-properties).

However, some elements don't play well in some browsers with changes to the `display` property. See this post (which applies to flex and grid): [Flexbox not working on button or fieldset elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276)

*You wrote:*

> Is setting a list to `display: grid` invalid? As all of the items seem to be randomly spaced.

Your items are not randomly spaced. The grid has four equal width columns, just like you specified:

*Your code:*

```
#footer_list{
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

*Your layout (as seen in Chrome, Firefox and Edge):*

[image]

So I'm not sure what you mean. But here's a simplified version of your code. Since you're already using the HTML5 [**`footer`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) element, which provides meaningful semantics, why the `ul`?

```css
footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 40px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

a {
  color: #001f3f !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="#">A Blah Blah Production</a>
  <a href="#">Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx</a>
  <a href="#">Email: support@company.com</a>
  <a href="#">Career Info</a>
</footer>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vq9b7c0e/14/)