# fieldset breaks my flex layout in angularjs-material

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, flexbox, angularjs-material

My problem is best shown by looking at two code examples:

The first one works fine when leaving out the `fieldset`

The second example shows that when the `fieldset` is active, the long text will move the layout out of the window. (in full page view)

When you shorten the text however it works and will conform to the flex layout.

Now my problem is that when I leave out the `fieldset` in the layout I am currently working on it works great for chrome and firefox, but fails in IE11. When I insert the `fieldset`, the layout looks fine under all browsers, but then the above-mentioned problem occurs when entering a long text in the text field and unfortunately this text field is for posting a link, so it is assumed that the text can get quite long easily.

I found a post showing how my page roughly looks when leaving out the `fieldset`.

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5084

here are the two snippets: 
the working one:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="MyApp">

<!--   <fieldset> -->
   <div style="display: flex; margin: 1em">
    <div flex="100" layout="row">
      
      <!-- main information field -->
      <div flex='90'>
        <div layout='row' flex='100'>
          <div layout="column" flex="50" >
            <label>Externe notities</label>
            <md-content>
            <div>kjfsdlafsdja;gaagj;gsahgh;gas;hoisgr;hoisohig;asgk;hlgshlksgfhli;gfhlisgohi;sghoisgdiasghvvsdbjkgasdohisgfdhusgfhu;;uhksgdjsgk;dxbhj;sgd;hisghsguho;sguho;susgsgdbjkvdjhsdihlsfdjbkdshoi;gsdbjk;gebuk;svdukssgho8sgou;hsegbusfdsugoiusdgogu;sgd;oiisgr;uesgodlosdsdgldsglidsgluisdg
              </div>
            </md-content>
          </div>
          <div layout="column" flex="50">
            <label>Interne notities</label>
            <md-content>
              <div>
                What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking
                at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web
                page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose
                (injected humour and the like).
              </div>
            </md-content>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- stop light -->
      <div flex='10'>
        <img height="100" src="https://www.portacon.nl/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/d/r/driekleurig_verkeerslicht_828x696_web.jpg" alt="stoplicht-wit" />
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- </fieldset> -->
</body>
```

and the not working one with `fieldset` enabled:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="MyApp">

<fieldset>
   <div style="display: flex; margin: 1em">
    <div flex="100" layout="row">
      
      <!-- main information field -->
      <div flex='90'>
        <div layout='row' flex='100'>
          <div layout="column" flex="50" >
            <label>Externe notities</label>
            <md-content>
            <div>kjfsdlafsdja;gaagj;gsahgh;gas;hoisgr;hoisohig;asgk;hlgshlksgfhli;gfhlisgohi;sghoisgdiasghvvsdbjkgasdohisgfdhusgfhu;;uhksgdjsgk;dxbhj;sgd;hisghsguho;sguho;susgsgdbjkvdjhsdihlsfdjbkdshoi;gsdbjk;gebuk;svdukssgho8sgou;hsegbusfdsugoiusdgogu;sgd;oiisgr;uesgodlosdsdgldsglidsgluisdg
              </div>
            </md-content>
          </div>
          <div layout="column" flex="50">
            <label>Interne notities</label>
            <md-content>
              <div>
                What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking
                at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web
                page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose
                (injected humour and the like).
              </div>
            </md-content>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- stop light -->
      <div flex='10'>
        <img height="100" src="https://www.portacon.nl/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/d/r/driekleurig_verkeerslicht_828x696_web.jpg" alt="stoplicht-wit" />
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</body>
```

**Question**

Is it possible and if yes, how do I get the layout to work with the `fieldset`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `min-inline-size: auto` to the `fieldset` to *fix* the width - `fieldset` has a computed style `min-inline-size: min-content` set by the browser user-agent. For user agents that do not support this property, you'd not have this *issue*.

See demo below:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="MyApp">
<fieldset style="min-inline-size: auto">
   <div style="display: flex; margin: 1em">
    <div flex="100" layout="row">
      
      <!-- main information field -->
      <div flex='90'>
        <div layout='row' flex='100'>
          <div layout="column" flex="50" >
            <label>Externe notities</label>
            <md-content>
            <div>kjfsdlafsdja;gaagj;gsahgh;gas;hoisgr;hoisohig;asgk;hlgshlksgfhli;gfhlisgohi;sghoisgdiasghvvsdbjkgasdohisgfdhusgfhu;;uhksgdjsgk;dxbhj;sgd;hisghsguho;sguho;susgsgdbjkvdjhsdihlsfdjbkdshoi;gsdbjk;gebuk;svdukssgho8sgou;hsegbusfdsugoiusdgogu;sgd;oiisgr;uesgodlosdsdgldsglidsgluisdg
              </div>
            </md-content>
          </div>
          <div layout="column" flex="50">
            <label>Interne notities</label>
            <md-content>
              <div>
                What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking
                at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web
                page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose
                (injected humour and the like).
              </div>
            </md-content>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- stop light -->
      <div flex='10'>
        <img height="100" src="https://www.portacon.nl/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/d/r/driekleurig_verkeerslicht_828x696_web.jpg" alt="stoplicht-wit" />
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</body>
```