# Is there a modernizr way of detecting flexbox support in button?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, modernizr

I was trying to implement a `flexbox` to a button. Current browsers work as expected. Testing it in **iPhone 5 (iOS 10.3.3)**, however, didn't work. So I was wondering if there's a ***Modernizr*** way of detecting **flexbox support in button**? Take note that this is specific to `button` tag and not the general flexbox support such as `Modernizr.flexbox`.

**UPDATE:** In my specific case I cannot edit the content of the button since it's a react component. So wrapping the content in a `span` is not an option as with this solution: [Flexbox not working on button or fieldset elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flexbox-not-working-on-button-or-fieldset-elements)

Comment: I would like to understand why you actually need this incredibly specific check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox not working on button or fieldset elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flexbox-not-working-on-button-or-fieldset-elements)

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I updated my question

Comment: @IanDevlin Because I'm using `flexbox` in the `button` tag and older version of Safari, I think, doesn't allow `flexbox` in buttons, which ruined the layout.

Comment: As of right now, anyway, I'm using os detection by means of `navigator.userAgent` & `navigator.appVersion`. But I was just wondering if I can use **Modernizr** to detect this lack of feature.