# column-count does not work within a fieldst in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fieldset, column-count

Has anyone noticed that fieldset tags do not support column-count or flex styling in Chrome? Does anyone know a workaround? Unfortunately this is created in an environment I cannot control. So, I can't change the HTML.

```
<fieldset style="column-count: 4;">No Bueno in Chrome</fieldset>
```

I've created a codepen that renders 4 columns of content. but if you view it in Chrome, it's only one column.

https://codepen.io/mrowka3d/pen/ZZqzVK?editors=1100

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox not working on button or fieldset elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flexbox-not-working-on-button-or-fieldset-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who may come across this, I was able to write a div within the fieldset and column count works great. Just add this wherever you can:

```
$( "fieldset" ).wrapInner( "<div></div>");
```