# Why don't children of flex button stretch to full height?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use horizontal flex elements inside a button, but they don't stretch vertically to the button height. Why?

Here is the snippet with `button` markup (does not stretch):

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.btn {
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
}

.red { background: red; }
.green { background: green; }
.blue { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">
    <div class="content red">Ho</div>
    <div class="content green">Ho</div>
    <div class="content blue">Ho</div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Here is the snippet with `div` markup (does stretch):

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.btn {
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
}

.red { background: red; }
.green { background: green; }
.blue { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn">
    <div class="content red">Ho</div>
    <div class="content green">Ho</div>
    <div class="content blue">Ho</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried `height: 100%` oir `self-align: stretch` in `.content` class, without success.

Comment: Why are you using `div` elements inside a `button`? That's not correct HTML at all. https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-button-element.html#the-button-element Most likely that this is the problem.

Comment: I did not know, why wouldn't I? :) What is the correct markup for button containing non-text children? `<div role="button">...</div>`?

Comment: @Red beat me to it. you can just have `<span>` instead of `<div>`. Or don't use `button` as a wrapper but a div with button-like functionalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer: [Flexbox not working on button or fieldset elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flexbox-not-working-on-button-or-fieldset-elements), in some browsers you can't set the display property of a button to anything else than `block` or `inline-block`.

The proposed solution is to add a wrapper:

(Note: as was already commented, a div inside a button is not correct HTML... 
Considder replacing it for span's.)

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.btn {
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
}

.red { background: red; }
.green { background: green; }
.blue { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content red">Ho</div>
      <div class="content green">Ho</div>
      <div class="content blue">Ho</div>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```