# Why do buttons on Chrome and Safari have a different default value for align-items than the w3 standards?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, flexbox

I've been reading about inconsistency of flexbox across browsers lately and I ended focusing on this particular example: making buttons flex containers.

It is a long known bug and there are some workarounds:

- https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-9
- [Flexbox not working on button or fieldset elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flexbox-not-working-on-button-or-fieldset-elements)

So, based on those links ^^ I expected to find some weird behaviours.

**Example 1**:

```css
.one {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.two {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.three {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
 <button class="two">
  <span class="three">
   Hello
  </span>
 </button>
</div>
```

What I don't understand about example 1 is that if you remove `align-items: stretch;` the yellow span doesn't stretch by default across the cross axis (here horizontal axis) on Chrome and Safari 
but does on Firefox.

**Example 2**:

```css
.one {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.two {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.three {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
 <button class="two">
  <span class="three">
   Hello
  </span>
 </button>
</div>
```

As expected, example 2 doesn't stretch the yellow button horizontally on Chrome and Safari but does on Firefox.

According to the W3C standards https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#align-items-property
the default value for `align-items` is `stretch` (or `normal` which, I think, does more of less the same thing in this context) for *all elements*.

What I found is that the default value of `align-items` for `buttons` in Safari and Chrome is `flex-start`. For Firefox, it is `normal`.

My question is: why don't Safari and Chrome respect the standard for the default value of `align-items` ?

Since they both share the value `flex-start` it might be a webkit thing but still doesn't explain why.

[User agent style for buttons in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7AiU.png)

PS1: I am using

- Chrome 79.0.3945.79
- Safari 12.1.1
- Firefox 70.0.1

PS2: FYI if I make it a flex container `row` even applying `align-items: stretch;` won't make a difference, still doesn't stretch across the cross axis but I would think that's because buttons are bad flex-containers: https://jsfiddle.net/jimousse/9by4zg32/1/

Comment: Default UA styles doesn't have to be the same, Exactly the same for properties that each browser support, you might say `Why this browser doesn't support this property?` i think this sort of questions should be directed to the browser support.

Comment: There are so many differences in defaults between browsers. That's why reset stylesheets exist. But yes, buttons do make bad flex containers. Have you tried `appearance:none`?

Comment: @MrLister you mean like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jimousse/9by4zg32/11/ ?
Doesn't to work :(

Comment: I think this is a bug in Webkit (and Blink) https://codepen.io/scheinercc/pen/ZEGwpKb

Comment: I filed this for Chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1065752 and also found this for Webkit https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=177503