# Flexbox not working properly for legend on Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a fieldset with a legend that has a text and a button.
I am trying to have the button right align using flexbox, it works fine on Chrome but not on Firefox.

I got a minimum code working to show the problem:

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
}

fieldset legend {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      Legend text
       <button type="button">
        Button text
      </button>
    </legend>
   </fieldset>
</main>
```

I want both both elements inside legend to be on the same line, as it showing on Chrome:
[image: as working on chrome]

But on Firefox i am getting the following result
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just wrap what you need in a div and apply flex there

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
}

 span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
    <span>
      Legend text
       <button type="button">
        Button text
      </button>
      </span>
    </legend>
   </fieldset>
</main>
```

Comment: do not use a div but a span. only phrasing content and hx tags are allowed inside a legend .  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend  &  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-legend-element

Answer (score 1):

[Flexbox is not supported with fieldset elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/8620333). Float can easily do the job here:

```css
fieldset legend {
  width: 100%;
}

fieldset legend button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Legend text
    <button type="button">
            Button text
          </button>
  </legend>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: `text-align-last:justify` should also work and allow vertical alignment. ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus true, deserve an answer IMO ;)