# Anchor and button elements render differently with same styles

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As title says-
I'm setting anchor and button to flex but their sizes are different.
Why does this happen? How can I achieve same visual on both elements with auto width?

```css
a,
button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  background: orange;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">asdf</a>
<button>asdf</button>
```

Comment: Anchor tags and button have different inherent styles. That makes it render differently. Use flex: 1/2 or something similar to achieve it

Comment: @RajeshPaudel in this situation `a` or `button` is a flex container. On what element should I use `flex: 1/2`?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say you need to use flex: 1/2 if it's inside. But this behaviour is mainly due to two box sizing. Content box and border box.

Comment: If it was box-sizing, then setting it to one or another value would help. But sadly, it's not :(

Comment: `flex` should be set on container, Setting on individual children is pointless.

Comment: Perhaps this will shed some light https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flex-grid-layouts-not-working-on-button-or-fieldset-elements

Comment: @MatJ the OP is setting flex to the parent, the text in the anchor for example is the flex item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem consists of 2 parts:

1. `button` and `a` render differently
2. I wanted `a` to render like `button` in this example. So the component I'm designing will not make its users to wrap it and so on and so forth.

The correct answer is arround `width` property set to `fit-content`. It has pretty good browser support and I'll try to use it.

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: Is this intended to be an answer? If so, please demonstrate more clearly what worked.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises from `button` not being allowed to have some of the other display properties depending on the engine. Wrapping `button` in a `span` is the easiest solution.

```
<a href="#">asdf</a>
<span><button>asdf</button></span>
```

```
a, span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  background: orange;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the same thing really

Comment: Care to explain why @Huangism

Comment: Your button is a flex item where OP's button is meant to be flex container

Comment: Right, well, they didn't specify that it needs to be a flex container.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here, in `width:auto`, auto tells the default value. The browser calculates the width.
```

Also both are different elements.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
 align-items: center;
}
a, 
button {
  width: auto;
  background: orange;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  padding-bottom:31px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">asdf</a>
  <button>asdf</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP asks for when the anchor and button are display flex, not as flex items

Comment: That is true but c'mon, it is quite obvious in the question, comparing anchor vs button when both are flex container

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the engine but the most probable cause of this in browsers is due to the **box-sizing** property of css. MDN defines box sizing as

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an
> element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element
> has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height
> to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This
> means that when you set width and height, you have to adjust the value
> you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added. For
> example, if you have four boxes with width: 25%;, if any has left or
> right padding or a left or right border, they will not by default fit
> on one line within the constraints of the parent container.

You can read more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing how using

But the closest you can reach is by using width as inherit. This will cause the elements to inherit width from parent.

```css
// Resetting both to have same type for similar render
a,button {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: unset;
}

a,
button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background: orange;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}

// Add width to parent element
.w-100 {
   width: 100vw;
}
// This will cause the default width behaviour to inherit from parent
a,button {
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-100">
  <a href="#">asdf</a>
  <button>asdf</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not seeing a difference on chrome on a mac